# Consolidate a time overlap in records and calculate hours worked?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a dataset where workers are logged into multiple systems at the same time and I would like to use SQL to account for the overlap in time and not overcount time worked. The final result should be the total work time per worker. I am working with SQL Server so I am limited to those functions. Below is the data set:

```
system  worker_id   start             end
  A        1    1/1/2019 10:00  1/1/2019 12:00
  B        1    1/1/2019 10:30  1/1/2019 11:15
  A        2    1/1/2019 10:00  1/1/2019 13:00
  B        2    1/1/2019 10:15  1/1/2019 11:15
  C        2    1/1/2019 10:20  1/1/2019 14:30
  A        3    1/1/2019 11:00  1/1/2019 13:00
  C        3    1/1/2019 12:00  1/1/2019 14:00
```

The result I am looking for:

```
worker_id   hours_worked
    1           2
    2          4.5
    3           3
```

Answer (score 1):

For your example data, you can use aggregation:

```
select worker_id,
       datediff(minute, min(start), max(end)) / 60.0 as decimal_hours
from t
group by worker_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's possible for there to be noncontiguous time ranges, taking the MIN and MAX would not cover all scenarios.  One way to make sure all possible outcomes are calculated would be to expand the time ranges using a TALLY function (or a numbers table).  [This answer uses dbo.fnTally](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) The query counts the number of distinct minutes per worker_id and divides by 60.0

dbo.fnTally

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnTally]
/**********************************************************************************************************************
    Jeff Moden Script on SSC: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/create-a-tally-function-fntally
**********************************************************************************************************************/
        (@ZeroOrOne BIT, @MaxN BIGINT)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
 RETURN WITH
  H2(N) AS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM (VALUES
                     (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    ,(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)
                    )V(N))            --16^2 or 256 rows
, H4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H2 a, H2 b) --16^4 or 65,536 rows
, H8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM H4 a, H4 b) --16^8 or 4,294,967,296 rows
            SELECT N = 0 WHERE @ZeroOrOne = 0 UNION ALL
            SELECT TOP(@MaxN)
                   N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N)
              FROM H8
;
```

query

```
select d.worker_id, count(distinct calc.dt)/60.0 hours_worked
from dataset d
     cross apply dbo.fnTally(0, datediff(minute, d.[start]. d.[end])) fn
     cross apply (values (dateadd(minute, fn.n, d.[start]))) calc(dt)
group by d.worker_id
order by d.worker_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows function. This is just a sample which matches with your dataset. You can use row number over the partition to filter out duplicates. I used distinct.

**As mentioned in above answer by @GordonLinoff shows it is the shortest way to get the result.**

```
SELECT Distinct
   A.workerId as Id
  ,CAST( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, A.[MIN START], A.[MAX END] ) / 60.0 AS DEcimal(10,1))  AS  [diff]
FROM
  (
     SELECT 
        T1.WorkerID,
        MIN(t1.[Start]) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.workerId order by T1.workerId) AS [MIN START]
        ,MAX(t1.[END]) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.workerId order by T1.workerId) AS [MAX END]
     FROM WorkerDetails t1 
   )AS A
```

[image: Result]